# Problem with order of elements when combining violin and point plot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot, pointplot

I am trying to make a combined plot using seaborn - violin plot with sticks inside and the mean+std pointplot on top of it. I have three categories that I want to use for hue. Somehow, the leftmost pointplot is hidden behind the inner part of violinplot (sticks, or whatever I put in there) - the rest is fine. Like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data =  sns.load_dataset('titanic')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)

sns.violinplot(data=data, x='alive', y='age', hue='class', palette='muted', size=2, inner='stick', ax=ax1)
ax1.legend_.remove()
fig.legend(loc='upper center', ncol=3, title='Class')

sns.pointplot(data=data, x='alive', y='age', hue='class', dodge=.54, join=False, errorbar='sd', capsize=0.05, palette='dark', ax=ax1,)
ax1.legend_.remove()

fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
```

[image: plot]

I want all pointplots to be above *all* of the violinplots. I tried using `zorder`, but it doesn't work with seaborn. Is there a way to set it up, or some other function/library that I can use to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use `zorder` not directly in `seaborn` but inside `plt.setp()` to change the property of an [Artist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html). Here is an example code snippet:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data =  sns.load_dataset('titanic')
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
sns.pointplot(data=data, x='alive', y='age', hue='class', dodge=.54, join=False, errorbar='sd', capsize=0.05, palette='dark', ax=ax1)
ax1.legend_.remove()
plt.setp(ax1.lines, zorder=100)
plt.setp(ax1.collections, zorder=100, label="")
sns.violinplot(data=data, x='alive', y='age', hue='class', palette='muted', size=2, inner='stick', ax=ax1)
ax1.legend_.remove()
fig.legend(loc='upper center', ncol=3, title='Class')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
```

which produces the following output:
[image]